# jQuery fileupload - get list of uploaded files

Tags: javascript, jquery, file-upload, jquery-file-upload

I'm using the very good jquery plugin [blueimp / jQuery-File-Upload](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload)

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  autoUpload: true
, filesContainer: '#attachments_presentation tbody'
, stop: function (e) {
    console.log(data);
  }
});
```

And I'm not able to do something very simple: get the list of uploaded files
(with their name on the server)

Firstly I naively though it would be stored on the file input so I could get the list with

```
$('#fileupload').val();
```

But it's not, so I though about something like

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload('getfiles');
```

I can't find the way from the docs

Can somebody tell me how I can get the list of uploaded file names in the server ?

---

**Update**

I'd like to get the uploaded files name on the **server** in order to be able to manage them afterwards.

For example:

- I upload a file named `trutruc.pdf`
- I upload `test.png`
- I re-upload a file named `trutruc.pdf`
- I delete the first file

The current list of files in the server should then be `test.png`, `trutruc (2).pdf`

---

**Update 2**

I'm using the [default php script shipped](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/blob/master/server/php/UploadHandler.php) with fileUpload

Answer (score 9, accepted):

When you instantiate the default plugin, there is a code portion which is retrieving all the previous uploaded files (assuming you haven't changed the server code) :

See on the `main.js` file line 70 :

```
    // Load existing files:
    $.ajax({
    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
    url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
        dataType: 'json',
        context: $('#fileupload')[0]
    }).done(function (result) {
        $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
            .call(this, null, {result: result});
    });
```

Than if you look further in your code, there is a table which will be filled out with the template :

```
<table role="presentation" class="table table-striped"><tbody class="files" data-toggle="modal-gallery" data-target="#modal-gallery"></tbody></table>
```

You could easily parse each  from that table after loading the files :

```
$('tbody.files tr').each(function(i, e) {
    //according to @Brandon's comment it's now p.name
    var name = $(e).find('td.name').text(); 
    var size = $(e).find('td.size').text();
    //etc.
});
```

Comment: I did my own template to show the files. I think it would be better to manage the file list from `done` & `destroy`

Comment: For anyone else that finds this solution to be correct; make sure you modify it from 'td.name' to 'p.name' since there has been a change it how it is generated :)

Answer (score 8):

I use UI version.
Here is script that grabs server links from table of files and populates array:

```
    var files = new Array();
    $("#fileupload td p.name a").each(function() {
        var name = $(this).attr("href");
        files.push(name);
    });
    alert(files.join('\n'));
```

Comment: by checking only elements having `href` attributes means you only consider the uploaded files to server and not in the que. This is what I was looking for. Great work!

Answer (score 2):

you can also try this

```
 $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadcompleted', function (e, data) {
     var filess= data.result.files[0];
        var filenam = filess.name;
       alert(filenam);
});
```

Comment: Please consider editing your post to add more explanation about what your code does and why it will solve the problem. An answer that mostly just contains code (even if it's working) usually wont help the OP to understand their problem.

Answer (score 1):

I had the same problem and after a few hours and tens of file uploads, I think I have the answer you need:

```
done: function (e, data) {
    response = data.response();
    parsedresponse = $.parseJSON(response.result);
    console.log(parsedresponse.files);
}
```

As you can see, you will find the uploaded files name at `parsedresponse.files[i].url` (*i* is the 0-based index of the uploaded files).

Ok... its the uploaded file's URL, but you'll be able to extract the final file name ...

Hope it helps.
(this is nowhere in the documentation, I managed to get to this solution by checking the Firebug console outputs)

Answer (score 1):

To get the list of uploaded file names from the **server**, requires server-side code:

*UploadHandler.php* is used to upload files to a directory/s on your server.

If you've downloaded the plug-in archive and extracted it to your server, the files will be stored in  php/files by default.
(Ensure that the php/files directory has server write permissions.)
see: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Setup

*UploadHandler.php* is just that, an upload handler.
It does not provide access to server files without a connection to the server.

JavaScript cannot access files on the **server**, so you'll need a php script to do so.
(Although JavaScript could possibly keep track of everything uploaded, renamed, and deleted.)

You can modify *UploadHandler.php* to connect to your database, and write the file paths (and any other data) to a files table during upload.
Then you can access your files via standard SQL queries:

### Modify *UploadHandler.php*:

1. Add your database connection parameters
2. Write an SQL query function
3. Write a second function to perform your query
4. Call the second function

see: https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Working-with-databases

Answer (score 1):

Well this is quite an old post, but this is something which worked very well for me so I thought to post it.

1. Bind the event to FileUploader (I did it in main.js):

   ```
       $('#fileupload').bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
           FileUploadDone(e, data);
       });
   ```
2. In your html file, use the following code to get the file name:

   ```
   function FileUploadDone(e, data) {
   for (x in data._response.result.files){
       if (data._response.result.files[x].error == "")
           alert(data._response.result.files[x].name);
       else
           alert(data._response.result.files[x].error);
   }}
   ```

You should watch the data object in firebug. This object encapsulates most of the information.

Answer (score 0):

If, you'r using the basic-plugin asmentioned in the [documentations](https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/Basic-plugin) you need to pass the data to the function in the done attribute.
change this:

```
stop: function (e) {
```

to this:

```
done: function (e, data) {
```

I don't know about the stop if you get it from one of the documentations pages then I think the same applied here you can't work with data if its not available.
Hope this help

Comment: `data` seems to contain only the original name of the file. I need the server file name, see my update

Comment: `data` is the data return from the server so if you want the new file name send it back from the server.

Comment: I don't understand, I know that `data` comes form the server but how can I get the new file names from it ?

Comment: Usually to get the new file name from the data object you need to send it back from the server, I don't know what language you'r using on the server but if it's PHP, it would be something like this: `echo json_encode(array('file_name' => $file_name));` and you'll get the $file_name from what you setit to in the PHP script.

Comment: I forgot to specify that I'm using the default php script shipped with `fileUpload`

Comment: Sorry, can't help you any further that script will take a long time for me to read and understand and I have a lot of work to do but as a general answer: you can read that script and find where the file_name is specified and add it (if it's not in the returned array) and then extracted from data in the client side. hope this helped.

Comment: Thank you for your time. Yes I think I'll have to make some reverse ingeneering here. I though it were documented somewhere I didn't see, that's why I asked.

Answer (score 0):

try use done method and put names in hidden input then select them:

```
$('#fileupload').fileupload({
  autoUpload: true
, filesContainer: '#attachments_presentation tbody'
, stop: function (e) {
    console.log(data);
  }
, done: function(e,data){
            var filess= data.files[0];
            var filenam = filess.name;
            data.context.text(filenam+' uploaded successfully.');
            $('#formId').append('<input type="hidden" name="fileName" value="'+filenam+'"/>');
}
});
```

Comment: Here `filess.name` contains the original name of the file. I need to name of the file on the server, it can be altered by the server uploader class, ie: `trutruc.pdf (2)` if `trutruc.pdf` already exists.

Answer (score 0):

to get file list on upload finished:

```
$('#fileupload').bind('fileuploadfinished', function (e, data) {
   console.log(data.originalFiles);
});
```

Answer (score 0):

```
 // Initialize the jQuery File Upload widget:
                $('#edit-product').fileupload({
                    // Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
                    //xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
                    disableImageResize: false,
                    autoUpload:false,
                    url: 'YOURURL'
                }).bind('fileuploaddone', function (e, data) {
                    console.log(data.result.files[0]);   
                });
```