# jQuery-File-Upload mysql select shows all files, not just the user's files

Tags: php, jquery, mysql, jquery-file-upload

Welcome,

I have a problem with jQuery-File-Upload. I integrated the plugin with MySQL -> https://github.com/blueimp/jQuery-File-Upload/wiki/PHP-MySQL-database-integration When I added file in to the database added record: `name file, id_user, active...` It's nice added.

When my website is loaded, loaded is list uploaded files: https://stackoverflow.com/a/15448692/2788495

I want to load only the user files currently loads all.

jQuery code:

```
    $.ajax({
// Uncomment the following to send cross-domain cookies:
//xhrFields: {withCredentials: true},
url: $('#fileupload').fileupload('option', 'url'),
    dataType: 'json',
    context: $('#fileupload')[0],
    formData:{
        user: '<?php echo $objSession->e_ident ?>'
    }
}).done(function (result) {
    $(this).fileupload('option', 'done')
        .call(this, null, {result: result});
});
```

PHP:

```
protected function handle_form_data($file, $index) {
    $file->title = @$_REQUEST['title'][$index];
    $file->description = @$_REQUEST['description'][$index];
    $file->user=@$_REQUEST['user'];
}
    protected function set_additional_file_properties($file) {
    parent::set_additional_file_properties($file);
    if ($_SERVER['REQUEST_METHOD'] === 'GET') {
        $sql = 'SELECT `id`,`user_id` FROM `'
            .$this->options['db_table'].'` WHERE `name`=? and user_id=?';
        $query = $this->db->prepare($sql);
        $query->bind_param('ss', $file->name, $file->user);
        $query->execute();
        $query->bind_result(
            $id,
            $user
        );
        while ($query->fetch()) {
            $file->id = $id;
            $file->user=$user;
        }
    }
}
```

In the JSON, doesn't have option: "id" and "user".

Answer (score 0):

I do not know if I understand right what you want to do.

I believe the user you want to show the files it uploaded are logged into your system through a session, is it?

And this "$objSession->e_ident" have the user id.

If I'm right, you should remove this:

`"user: '<?php echo $objSession->e_ident ?>'"`  from the ajax requisition, stuffs like user id should be only in server session file and never on page.

You should put it the user id direct on query bind, like this:
`$query->bind_param('ss', $file->name, $objSession->e_ident);`

Now your problem, your query looks right, is $objSession->e_ident giving really the correct id to the users?

Into database which value user_id column have?

Answer (score 0):

This won't work. It doesn't read a file list from the database. The DB is there to capture additional information about the file. It reads the contents of the files directory.

The solution is to enable user_dirs.

Change line 50ish

```
'user_dirs' => false,
```

to

```
'user_dirs' => true,
```

I assume you have the logged in user creating a user id session. Line 217...

```
protected function get_user_id() {
@session_start();
return session_id();
}
```

Change that to

```
protected function get_user_id() {
return $_SESSION['user_id'];
}
```

Or whatever your session user id is. make sure on index.php your session is active on that page.

What this does is create a directory that has the same name as you user's session user_id. So they can only see the files in that directory.