# AngularJS - How to list the filenames from a given folder?

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, angularjs, meanjs

I have this folder/directory 'x' in the public folder of my application.
Now I have path name till the folder i.e., /path/to/dir/x , but I don't know the names of the files in this directory. Now I need to provide URL links to the files in the html a tag's href attribute.

How do I list the name of the files in this directory?

Comment: AngularJS is client side(runs in browser) you have to do this in server side and get the information using `$http`

Comment: Try this solution [Link][1] or [enter link description here][2] 


  [1]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/20822273/best-way-to-get-folder-and-file-list-in-javascript
  [2]: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/15448574/jquery-fileupload-get-list-of-uploaded-files

Comment: Use `Directory.GetFiles(path)` method to list all the files and then in angular use `ng-repeat` and build a URL on the client.

Comment: Alternatively, you can use AJAX calls: http://stackoverflow.com/a/11213851/2220216

Answer (score 1):

Angular is a client side library. Getting files from file directories is a backend capability.

Comment: Welcome to StackOverflow! Thanks for this answer, but that's already been said in the first comment, so this doesn't add anything.

Comment: Wrong! We have now 2017. We are using angular in electron that is running locally on desktop. So using the file system is a valid question.

Comment: @SandorRozsa So is it possible?