# Jquery Uploader Blueimp can't access error index

Tags: javascript, jquery

Been looking a couple of hours for a solution to this problem.
So if you add a file to the queue and there has been an error there's an error added to the data file index. If I do a console.log(data) I see that the error index exists (screenshot) but when I try to access it with data.error it says undefined. What's going on here?

So if I do console.log(data.error) I get a undefined. Why is this?

[screenshot of console.log of data](https://i.stack.imgur.com/5UKDv.png)

I really want to know why this isn't working but is there another way to get a list of files with errors currently in the queue? 
Or to know that there is a error in the queue?

Comment: create a fiddle, it would be helpful :)

Comment: according to error message, you are not uploading the required file(check file extension)

Comment: have a look at related thread http://stackoverflow.com/a/15448692/4361743